# How do I use VLC to create a video wall effect

Tags: video, vlc

I'm trying to build a system that plays a video, such as a scenic landscape or timelapse, split up across 3 large HDTVs to effectively create one large TV.

So far, I've got the computer hooked up and working, with the desktop extended to the two extra displays, for an effective resolution of 3240x1920 split into three desktops. However, if I try to maximize my video player, it only uses one screen, as you might expect with normal multi-monitor usage.

I heard that VLC has a "wall" feature that allows you to split a video into segments for this specific purpose, but so far I've been unable to get it working. I have two problems:

1. First, the wall feature simply doesn't work. It creates 3 windows, each of which shows the full video image, rather than a segment, with a strange flickering green line down the left side of them. Does this feature only work with certain video types? Or is something else causing this?
2. The created windows can be maximized, but I can't figure out how to make them fullscreen, such that only the video shows, hiding the taskbar and program tray.

I'm currently running VLC on Windows, but I had the same problems when Ubuntu was installed, and I could very easily switch back to using Ubuntu or even a different Linux distro later on.